# What is the meaning of “3 to 1 odds against success”?

Tags: terminology, odds

I came across this passage while reading about forecasts, but I am not sure if my interpretation of the odds below is correct. I am interpreting it as there a 75% of success, is that correct?

> In  1961,  when  the  CIA  was  planning  to topple  the  Castro  government  by  landing  a  small  army  of  Cuban expatriates  at  the  Bay  of  Pigs,  President  John  F.  Kennedy  turned  to the  military  for  an  unbiased  assessment.  The  Joint  Chiefs  of  Staff concluded that the plan had a “fair chance” of success. The man who wrote the words “fair chance” later said he had in mind **odds of 3 to 1 against  success**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds):

> Odds provide a measure of the likelihood of a particular outcome. They are calculated as the ratio of the number of events that produce that outcome to the number that do not.

So out of 4 (hypothetical) re-runs of this scenario, 3 would have been unsuccessful and 1 successful (since the odds were *against* success), for a 25% success chance.